# LINQ Lambda query 'select' not working with oData

Tags: c#, linq, odata

I'm currently trying to understand some of the fundamentals with LINQ. I have been using LINQPad to query the Netflix OData source.

> **Source:** http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog/

I can't seem to select single properties when using a lambda query - the comprehension query works perfectly. I found a snippet of code that performs a more complex query using lambdas on the Netflix oData source, and this seems to work fine for returning one property of the entity.

```
// works fine
var compQuery = from t in Titles
                where t.ReleaseYear == 2007
                select new { t.Name };
compQuery.Dump();   



// fails: "Can only specify query options (orderby, where, take, skip) after last navigation."
var lambdaQuery = Titles
            .Where(t => t.ReleaseYear == 2007)
            .Select(t => t.Name);

lambdaQuery.Dump(); 


// works fine - found on SO.
var lambdaQuery2 = People
    .Expand("TitlesActedIn")
    .Where(p => p.Name == "George Lucas")
    .First()
    .TitlesActedIn.Select(t => t.ShortName);              

lambdaQuery2.Dump();
```

**Could anyone shed some light as to why the basic lambda query is failing when asked to return one property?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this- it is what is actually equivalent to your first one:

```
// fails: "Can only specify query options (orderby, where, take, skip) after last navigation."
var lambdaQuery = Titles
            .Where(t => t.ReleaseYear == 2007)
            .Select(t => new { t.Name });

lambdaQuery.Dump();
```

Comment: ahhh, I tried that now and it works! - What I don't understand is how the other lambda query (people) doesn't require me to create an anonymous type for projection?

Comment: Because you call `.First()` on it, which materializes the results- it sucks down the whole record and then selects out the properties in memory on the client.

Comment: Would you explain why it requires using anonymous type?
Thanks

Comment: It doesn't require an anonymous type- you could use a concrete class, for instance. I used an anonymous type here to illustrate how to get the single property that the OP wanted.

Answer (score 14):

OData doesn't have support for projecting to properties - you can work around this though:

```
var lambdaQuery = Titles
            .Where(t => t.ReleaseYear == 2007)
            .Select(x=> new { x.Name })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(t => t.Name);
```

Using `AsEnumerable()` forces the last part of the query to be executed in Linq-to-Objects context (instead of an OData query) where the projection works just fine.

Comment: Thanks, that works - I've found some more info here regarding the AsEnumerable - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/d427cbf6-4d8a-42ee-9799-d5ca79e581dc

Comment: I wish I could test this from work (Netflix blocked here) but is the first projection actually necessary? It seems a bit redundant here.

Comment: @JeffMercado: According to Odata (and the link in the comments above) an odata projection will send the entity itself, but leaving out the properties that are not needed - so it is best for performance to leave this in to reduce the amount of data that goes over the wire

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Yeah that certainly makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Are you sure you need this part   .Select(x=> new { x.Name })  ?   Oh I see I ran this in linqpad before adding question  -  It that part is commented out it tries to pull all the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Using the answers given, I have ran some tests and found some interesting things regarding execution time:

```
// Avg Execution Time: 5 seconds
var query1 = Titles
            .Where(t => t.ReleaseYear == 2007)
            .Select(t => new {t.Name});     
query1.Dump();


// Avg Execution Time: 15 seconds
var query2 = Titles
            .Where(t => t.ReleaseYear == 2007)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(t => t.Name);       
query2.Dump();
```

So am I right in thinking that in query 1, only the 'Name' property is being returned? Whereas in query 2, the 'AsEnumerable()' method is bringing back the entity with all property values, hence longer execution time?

Comment: Yes, the transfered data is much larger for query2 AND since you are querying entire entities they get change-tracked by the context.